# HighStock BaseSeries

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone please explain the significance of baseSeries property in navigator of HighStock. Also with small example.

I have gone through api but there is no example there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Series in navigator is set by baseSeries property. If you have multiple series you can choose which one should be in navigator.
Indexation of series starts at 0.

Examples:

[string](http://jsfiddle.net/f52j1mkx/)

[integer](http://jsfiddle.net/f52j1mkx/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator: {
            baseSeries: '1' //or 1 will set series named '2nd'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: '1st',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        }, {
            name: '2nd',
            data: [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
        },{
            name: '3rd',
            data: [3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1]
        }]
    });
});
```